# How to visualize Actor message flow with Akka 2.1.2?

Tags: scala, akka, actor

I'm using Akka 2.1.2 and SPRAY library to answer RESTful request. I want to balance requests to several nodes and have been using this tutorial: [Balancing Workload Across Nodes with Akka 2](http://letitcrash.com/post/29044669086/balancing-workload-across-nodes-with-akka-2)

Apart from Typesafe's console (Atmos) is there a toolkit to visualize the message processing distribution on actor systems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no such framework other than Typesafe's console.